# Disabling autocorrect in microsoft edge

Tags: browser, windows

This seems like it should be an easy fix but the only answers that I can find are for other versions.

I tried the solution proposed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/disable-autocorrect-in-microsoft-edge-feature/51b2a61b-2e4d-485a-ab31-0be3027e681e) but disabling autocorrect misspelled words did not work.

[image]

Elsewhere, it seems to be [hopeless](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/disable-autocorrect-in-microsoft-edge-feature/51b2a61b-2e4d-485a-ab31-0be3027e681e)...

And since stackexchange provides much better mechanisms for sorting through answers, I'm posting here instead of answers.microsoft.com

Similar posts in stackexchange:
[How to change spell check language in Microsoft Edge](https://superuser.com/questions/1289903/how-to-change-spell-check-language-in-microsoft-edge)

Answer (score 1):

## Local Group Policy fix

- press **<kbd>WIN</kbd>**+**<kbd>R</kbd>**
- type **gpedit.msc**
- go to: **`User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options`**
- enable **Turn off autocorrect...**
- enable **Turn off highlight...**
- restart your PC
  [image]

## Windows/System32 fix

- go to **`C:\Windows`**
- right-click on **System32** folder
- select **`Properties > Security > Advanced > Owner`**
- set permissions to **read and write** to gain ownership of the files
- enter **`C:\Windows\System32`**
- rename **MsSpellCheckingHost.exe** to **MsSpellCheckingHost.exe.STOP**
- rename **MsSpellCheckingFacility.dll** to **MsSpellCheckingFacility.dll.STOP**
- restart your PC

## Script Extension fix

- download Tampermonkey - https://tampermonkey.net/?ext=dhdg&browser=edge
- install this script - https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/39190-disable-spellcheck-globally
- restart your PC

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64355660/13683677) on Stack Overflow

> What I found to do it disable autocorrect in the new Chromium-based Edge, is to right-click on a word that has been autocorrected. It should list the original word with the option to restore it. Beneath that, there should be an option to either disable autocorrect for that site or permanently. Select your preference and autocorrect should stop bugging you. Hope to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to *uncheck* in your screenshot:

```
Show text suggestions as I type ...
```

in software and hardware keyboard, just in case.